# How can I select some projects to be eligible to be built by agents

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I've created successfully my 1st Jenkins agent, but I don't want to be used to all the projects, so I've chosen the {{Only selected projects}} option.

But how can I choose the projects?
I've looked at Jenkins management, and the configuration of a project, and I don't see the needed setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tie jobs to slaves in the jobs' configuration: go to ${jenkins url}/job/${job name}/configure and look for the **Restrict where this project can be run** field in the general settings:

[image: Restrict where this project can be run]

You can type names of slaves there, or even better, use tags assigned to slaves. You can use logical expressions like `||` and `&&`, too.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on ameba's answer you can set labels for a node in the node configuration settings and therefore label nodes with the toolchains or tools that you require.

Then in jenkins-pipeline you can do the following:

```
node('TOOL label')
{
    stage('build using TOOL') {
    }
}
```

the node section tell jenkins to find a node with that label and to use it for the following block of code.